# SQL select calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

> Below are the things I'm using
>
> - [lahman's baseball -database](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/)
> - 2015 SQL version of the database.
> - Microsoft SQL server management studio v17.7
> - I'm using "Los Angeles Dodgers" statistics and I'm basing my selects of
>     the website and pulling from the above database [Website for ESPN Los Angeles Dodgers](http://www.espn.com/mlb/team/stats/batting/_/name/lad/year/2012)

I'm trying to recreate the website with 7 individual select statements. I'm having issues with my second select statements at the moment, The purpose of the second is to provide a totals row at the bottom like they do on the website.

> ( So my main question is can someone help with fixing my second select.)
>
> ( My second question can i get some assistance on creating 5 other
>   selects statements that correspond with the image below.)

[image: Click for 5 selects image]

(1st)
**Main Body Select** :

```
SELECT
  nameFirst + ' ' + nameLast AS Name,
  G AS GP,
  AB,
  R,
  H,
  H - B2 - B3 - HR AS S,
  B2 AS '2B',
  B3 AS '3B',
  HR,
  RBI,
  (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4)) AS 'TB',
  BB,
  SO,
  SB,
  (H * 1.0) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END) AS 'BA',
  (CASE
    WHEN (H + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ((H + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN (AB + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 1.0
    ELSE ((AB + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END) AS 'OBP',
  (CASE
    WHEN (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4))
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END) AS 'SLG',
  (CASE
    WHEN (H + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ((H + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN (AB + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 1.0
    ELSE ((AB + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END) +
  (CASE
    WHEN (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4))
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END) AS 'OPS'
FROM Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN Batting
  ON Players.playerIDpk = Batting.playerID
WHERE teamID = 'LAN'
AND yearID = '2012'
ORDER BY BA DESC
```

[Click Here - For Image of above select output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLVwL.jpg)

(2nd)
**Total Select:**

```
SELECT
  '' AS Total,
  '162' AS 'GP',
  SUM(AB) AS 'AB',
  SUM(R) AS 'R',
  SUM(H) AS 'H',
  SUM(B2) AS '2B',
  SUM(B3) AS '3B',
  SUM(HR) AS HR,
  SUM(RBI) AS RBI,
  SUM((((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4))) AS 'TB',
  SUM(BB) AS BB,
  SUM(SO) AS 'SO',
  SUM(SB) AS 'SB',
  AVG((H * 1.0) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END)) AS 'BA',
  AVG((CASE
    WHEN (H + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ((H + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN (AB + BB + HBP) = 0 THEN 1.0
    ELSE ((AB + BB + HBP) * 1.0)
  END)) AS 'OBP',
  AVG((CASE
    WHEN (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4))
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END)) AS 'SLG',
  AVG((CASE
    WHEN (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (((H - B2 - B3 - HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR * 4))
  END) / (CASE
    WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE AB
  END)) AS 'OPS'
FROM Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN Batting
  ON Players.playerIDpk = Batting.playerID
WHERE teamID = 'LAN'
AND yearID = '2012'
```

> Here's what my total select returns and its incorrect.

[image: Incorrect Images]

> Below is what it should return when i run the select for totals i don't know what i did wrong.

[image: Correct Image]

Comment: If it were slightly off, I'd be happy to edit for you.

Comment: Make it easy to help you. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Why do you even include the first query when the question is all about the second query, please remove unnecessary information from the question.

Comment: i added it so that they can see my complete select statement of calculations from the data base. ill make the changes in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at only the total value for the column `BA` it is clear that you are not doing the same calculations as them, instead of calculating average values you should calculate the ratio betweens the sum of the columns `H` and `AB`

So replace

```
AVG((H * 1.0) / (CASE
  WHEN AB = 0 THEN 1
  ELSE AB
END)) AS 'BA',
```

with

```
SUM(H) / SUM(AB) AS 'BA'
```

I haven't checked the other incorrect columns but I assume it's the same issue.

Comment: I also thought that  as well, Except for when i do that it returns a zero nothing else in that column.

Comment: Could be an integer division problem, have you tried to multiply by 1.0 to cast to double?